# how to fit the following equation like ln(x.....) with cftool in matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I have a fit problem with equation: `y = f(x,z) = (c)*log((z-a)/((a-b)*x)+1)` in matlab. and `x,y,z` are the varibales (`x>0,y>0,z<0`). the unkown coefficients are a,b, and c. In addtion, range of `a` and `b` is between [-20,-1].

By calling a custom equation in cftools like:
[image: custom equation in cftools...]

[image: fit errors ...]

Moreover, the "custom equation" in ctools from MATLAB software is used, and I have got error "Complex value computed by model function, and fitting cannot continue. Try using or tightening upper and lower bounds on coefficients.
". The problem may be caused by the noise data leading the value of ((z-a)/((a-b)*x)+1) less than zero.

Does anyone has the same problem and how to solver it？

Comment: What is your dataset looks like?